# In vscode how do I pass in arguments from launch.json or have a template in tasks.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a build script that supports ~40 different commands. I rather not write out 40 task even if its a copy/paste with an argument or two changed. Is there some way I have can one or two task and pass the arguments in from launch.json? or have a template that all my task use and I can change the args there?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable)

It has a few commands that can remember what you have picked from a list and use that information in `launch.json` and `tasks.json`.

You can choose to store the argument variations of the build script in `launch.json` and use `extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember` to convert the choice to a number of stored variables that can be used in `launch.json` and `tasks.json` with the command `extension.commandvariable.remember`.

You can also store all the configuration options in a json file:

```json
{
  "build": {
    "foo": {
      "arg1": 10,
      "arg2": "-v"
    },
    "bar": {
      "arg1": 50,
      "arg2": "-b"
    }
  }
}
```

In `launch.json` use `extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember` to pick a build variant (`foo` or `bar`) and use this picked string in the `json` property of command `extension.commandvariable.file.content` in `launch.json` and `tasks.json`.

I will add the possibility that `key` and `json` property can contain variables so you can use the remember variable (`${remember:arg1}`) in v1.26 of the extension.

`launch.json`

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js${input:pickBuild}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Build"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "pickBuild",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember",
      "args": {
        "key": "empty",
        "options": [
          ["foo", {"buildvariant":"foo"}],
          ["bar", {"buildvariant":"bar"}],
        "description": "Pick a build variant"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This trick returns an empty string but stores the `buildvariant` to be used in `tasks.json`. If you have to configure the launch based on the build you can return a string with content. I will add the key `empty` to the default remember store in v1.26.

`tasks.json`

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "python",
      "args": [ "build.py", "${input:buildArg1}", "${input:buildArg2}" ],
    },
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "buildArg1",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
      "args": {
        "fileName": "${workspaceFolder}/build-options.json",
        "json": "content.${remember:buildvariant}.arg1",
        "default": "--dummy",
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "buildArg2",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
      "args": {
        "fileName": "${workspaceFolder}/build-options.json",
        "json": "content.${remember:buildvariant}.arg2",
        "default": "--dummy",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you use the `extension.commandvariable.file.pickFile` in `launch.json` you can use this file path in the command `extension.commandvariable.file.content`

**Edit**

In v1.26 I have added the possibility to [add key-value pairs to the remember storage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#remember) and return an empty string. This makes it possible for a launch configuration to set key-values to be used in a task. Just use `${input:name}` anywhere in a launch property string that supports variables.

Comment: was a bit cumbersome to understand the documentation but very nice! now i can define stores in launch.json load them by referencing them somewhere in a launchconfig (usefulll if multiple launchconfigs, and the variable returns empty)

Only issue i have if i want to pass an array (build arguments) i get an error that extensions.commandvariable.remember did not return resulttype of string.  If you could make it work with arrays this would be fantastic! Since arguments don't work well if they're written as string in vscode!

Comment: @S.JohnFagone can you create an issue at the Command Variable repo with an example of the array case. Which part of the documentation was hard to understand?

Comment: i created the issue "Global Settings for behaviour #18" but for another case. I checked and there is no way to split the string into args since the the replacement of input fields in vscode happens at a later point in time.

The documentation could have more expressive examples. I just stared today vscode and came across this and it was difficult to get the gist of it as a newbie. all the examples were in the same file and the differentation between how to store a value and how to read a value (from whichever source and how to trigger the store of a value) got me confused in the beginning

Comment: @S.JohnFagone do you have a link for the issue #18? It is not at the Command Variable repo. If you want to add a couple of arguments you can add the `${input}` variable in the command string, then VSC does not quote the individual parts. All the variable storage/retrieve is named `remember` in the doc page, just find for that word and you get all the locations where it is relevant. VSC does not have a multipage doc structure. You can use the `extension.commandvariable.transform` command to split a remember value, if you set the `text` property to use a `${remember:name}` variable

Comment: https://github.com/ArturoDent/launch-config/issues/18

Comment: @S.JohnFagone What has the extension Launch-Config to do with the CommandVariable extension, in the issue you don't use any of the launch-config exported commands, please fix the format of the 2 starting code blocks, use language `jsonc`

Comment: sorry this was the repo that got opened when klickin on the repo link on the vsode market side! i didn't check if it was the correct repo.  also i use jsonc the formatting is broken because copy paste..

Comment: @S.JohnFagone at the top of this answer is a link to the marketplace page of the extension, on that page is a link to the repo